# Best way to design a database with one person with different roles

Tags: database-design, view

We've been browsing for a while looking for an answer to this, but any of them suited exactly my needs, I hope is a relevant question.

We have a database for managing books. In this database, a same person can be author and editor, or author and translator.

We have chosen this schema:

[image]

However, wen we design the view for books, that have to have the title, the author, the translator, etc., we have to do it like this, in order to get the name of the person related to the role:

[image]

But we know that it's not the best way. I think is a relevant question, because this problem is a very common one in order to design a good and solid database, and this knowledge is not always specified in manuals.

Thank you!

Comment: I think your schema is pretty good. What I don't get from the question is what exactly the problem is.

Comment: Thank you! It's because in order to do the view, we think that maybe dupolicate or tirplicate peronsa and idioma is not a good solution, and that maybe the schema lacks some consistency.

Comment: With "to do the view", do you mean that the query (or view) has to reference some tables 2 or 3 times?

Comment: Yes, sorry, that's exact!

Comment: Then that is fine, I see no problem. Queries that reference a table more than once are pretty common. What could be improved is the `autor` (and the other 2 tables (traductor and editor.) The `id_autor` and `persona_id_persona` do not need to be 2 columns. One column (say `id_autor`) can be both the primary key and a foreign key to `persona`.

Comment: Then some joins could skip the `autor` table, like in your example, and join directly the `libro_has_autor` to `persona`.

Comment: ypercube, thank you very much. I cannot update your comments, but if you answer I will mark your answer as the one i'm looking for, Thank you again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to help other people with same doubts: the good answer is ypercube's commentary.